# How can I delete a data node which is not empty in zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

For deleting a node in zookeeper from command line interface there is a delete command. When I run it, it says:

```
Node not empty: /testNode
```

I am using [this guide](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperStarted.html).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `zkCli` provides the `rmr` (deprecated) or `deleteall` command for this purpose.  It will recursively delete all nodes under the path.  This command did not [appear until version 3.4.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-729).  The documentation link you provided is for version `3.3.3`.

Answer (score 1):

deleteall nodeName

For example:
deleteall /hbase
works for me in hbase 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command in Java:

`zkClient.deleteRecursive(ZkUtils.getTopicPath(topicName));`

Comment: Looks like the same does Zk Cli according to `org.apache.zookeeper.cli.DeleteAllCommand#exec`